# Calling '' with incomplete return type ''

Tags: c, struct, definition, incomplete-type

Despites all my verifications, I still can't figure what is wrong with the 10 first lines of my program...

```
typedef struct Case_PN Case_PN;

struct Case_PN {
    unsigned entier;
    unsigned flottant;
    union {
        int i;
        double f;
    } u;
};

Case_PN case_pn_init (unsigned type, int val1 , double val2){
    Case_PN c = {0};
    if (type==0){
        c.entier =1; c.flottant = 0; c.u.i =val1;
    }
    else {
        c.entier =0; c.flottant =1; c.u.f = val2;
    }
    return c;
}
```

To explain a little bit, `Case_PN` is just a type union, as an int when entier ==1, and a float in the other cases. `case_pn_init` initialize such a structure.
But the issue is during the compilation :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    case_pn_init(0,1,(8.0));
  
    return 0;
}
```

With a wonderful error message :

> **Calling 'case_pn_init' with incomplete return type 'Case_PN' (aka 'struct Case_PN')**

How can I repair it ?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `struct Case_PN` and `Case_PN` are not the same.

Comment: The only error I see in the edited code is the double `;;` after the struct definition. After removing one, it [compiles fine](https://godbolt.org/z/5v87rhdrb).

Comment: @TedLyngmo It still doesn't work on Xcode and that is my issue : it really seems right

Comment: If your code looks like the one I linked to, your compiler may be broken. I've tested it with [four different compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/Pexfn9daM)

Comment: BTW, what's your compiler (is it clang?) and how do you compile this code? Is it a single source code?

Comment: @Bob__ I don't know... I'm coding on Xcode (and btw I created a brand new file and pasted all this... However I got the same error...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function declaration

```
Case_PN case_pn_init (unsigned type, int val1 , double val2){
```

there is used undefined type `Case_PN`.

It seems you mean

```
struct Case_PN case_pn_init (unsigned type, int val1 , double val2){
    struct Case_PN c = {0};
    //...
```

Even if you used a typedef like for example

```
typedef struct Case_PN Case_PN;

Case_PN case_pn_init (unsigned type, int val1 , double val2){
```

then in any case the structure definition shall be before the function definition.

It seems the translation unit with main where the function is called does not see the structure  definition. It sees only the typedef declaration.

Place the structure definition in the header and include the header everywhere where the function is defined and called.

Comment: Actually I declared typedef struct Case_PN Case_PN before so... It should not be an the issue...

Comment: @Romanion Then provide the corresponding code.

Comment: I edited my post sorry... Do you want the prototype too ?

Comment: @Romanion See my updated answer.

Comment: What do you mean ? I declared the struct before case_pn _init ...

Comment: @Romanion I mean that the complete structure definition shall be visible in the point of the function definition and its call and the error message says about that.

Comment: Sorry, but what is "the point of the fonction", I really don't uderstand what is wrong with my struct declaration (please provide a concrete example, i can't see the point...)

Comment: @Romanion What is unclear? You till now are unable to provide a relevant code. Define the structure in the header and include the header where the function is defined and called. Is it clear?

Comment: But... I already did it, here's my header :`#ifndef PN_package_h
#define PN_package_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif /* PN_package_h */

typedef struct Case_PN Case_PN;
struct Case_PN;

Case_PN case_pn_init (unsigned type, int val1 , double val2);`

Comment: @Romanion And where is there the structure definition?

Comment: @VladimirfromMoscow And yes, I called #include <stdio.h>,  #include <stdlib.h> and #include "PN_file.h" before all of my 3 files used for the code

Comment: @VladimirfromMoscow Isn't it `struct Case_PN `? Or should I rewrite the entire definition (I already tried and got an error)

Comment: @Romanion Do you understand the human language? One more where is there in the header the structure definition?

Comment: @Romanion Here is the structure definition struct Case_PN {
    unsigned entier;
    unsigned flottant;
    union {
        int i;
        double f;
    } u;
}; Place it in the header.

Comment: @VladimirfromMoscow It is just right before `typedef struct Case_PN' and after 'Case_PN case_pn_init ([...])`

Comment: @VladimirfromMoscow Well I'm sorry ot works now... Thank you and excuse me for my slowness...

Comment: @VladimirfromMoscow This kind of mistakes didn't cause any error in my previous codes it's strange